# Getting "ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value" Error using mariadb

Tags: mariadb, haproxy

While creating a haproxy_check user in MariaDB I am getting error ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value, what I need to do?

Comment: You are inserting data into a table but fail to give data for all fields. If you are doing this manually, make sure to specify values for all fields that does not have default values.

Comment: I would advise investing more time in writing questions. I talking about an error, you will get better answers describing the operation that led to that error.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you are running mariadb with SSL enabled but don't have a cipher set. You have two options:

- start the server without SSL enabled if you don't require encrypted connections (remove the -ssl flag from the config options)
- set the `ssl_cipher` variable. See the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/secure-connections-overview/) for a more complete picture.

Use the following commands on MariaDB or MySQL:

```
alter table user change column ssl_cipher ssl_cipher blob null ; 
alter table user change column x509_issuer x509_issuer blob null ; 
alter table user change column x509_subject x509_subject blob null ; 
alter table user change column authentication_string authentication_string blob null
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner using MySQL, and encountered this exact same error.

I tried to create a user in the user table, using `INSERT INTO` rather than using the `CREATE USER` command.

Please read the [6.2.8 Adding Accounts, Assigning Privileges, and Dropping](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html) - MySQL documentation.

There is even a warning,

> Note
>
> Direct modification of grant tables using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is discouraged and done at your own risk.